# "Provided value to SecureStore is larger than 2048 bytes" while trying to store Google OAuth token

Tags: expo, google-signin

I'm implementing Google login to my Expo app using Supabase, I set it up to store the tokens on expo-secure-store, but when I login I get the following warning:

> Provided value to SecureStore is larger than 2048 bytes. An attempt to store such a value will throw an error in SDK 35.

I a using Expo 48. The token I'm trying to store is the following (redacted):

```
{"access_token":"<REDACTED>","token_type":"<REDACTED>","expires_in":<REDACTED>,"refresh_token":"<REDACTED>","user":{"id":"<REDACTED>","aud":"<REDACTED>","role":"<REDACTED>","email":"<REDACTED>","email_confirmed_at":"<REDACTED>","phone":"<REDACTED>","confirmed_at":"<REDACTED>","last_sign_in_at":"<REDACTED>","app_metadata":{"provider":"<REDACTED>","providers":["<REDACTED>"]},"user_metadata":{"avatar_url":"<REDACTED>","email":"<REDACTED>","email_verified":<REDACTED>,"full_name":"<REDACTED>","iss":"<REDACTED>","name":"<REDACTED>","picture":"<REDACTED>","provider_id":"<REDACTED>","sub":"<REDACTED>"},"identities":[{"id":"<REDACTED>","user_id":"<REDACTED>","identity_data":{"avatar_url":"<REDACTED>","email":"<REDACTED>","email_verified":<REDACTED>,"full_name":"<REDACTED>","iss":"<REDACTED>","name":"<REDACTED>","picture":"<REDACTED>","provider_id":"<REDACTED>","sub":"<REDACTED>"},"provider":"<REDACTED>","last_sign_in_at":"<REDACTED>","created_at":"<REDACTED>","updated_at":"<REDACTED>"}],"created_at":"<REDACTED>","updated_at":"<REDACTED>"},"expires_at":<REDACTED>}
```

I suppose I'm not the first trying to implement Google login through Expo so I was wondering what's the commonly accepted solution to this problem?

Comment: FYI:  login doesn't have a refresh token thats oauth2 consent

Comment: Using GitHub login provider it's the same problem.

Comment: I'm using expo-unlimited-secure-store

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the ideal answer, but I ended up removing less sensitive user metadata from the session object returned from supabase:

```
function removeUserMetaData(itemValue: string) {
    let parsedItemValue = JSON.parse(itemValue);

    // Remove properties from the object
    if (parsedItemValue) {
        delete parsedItemValue.user?.identities;
        delete parsedItemValue.user?.user_metadata;
    }
    // Convert the modified object back to a JSON string
    return JSON.stringify(parsedItemValue);
}

const ExpoSecureStoreAdapter = {
    getItem: async (key: string) => {
        return SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
    },
    setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
        SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, removeUserMetaData(value));
    },
    removeItem: (key: string) => {
        SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key);
    },
};
```

And storing the user metadata in separate non secure storage.

Answer (score 1):

We've clarified SecureStore usage and outlined an option for encrypting the session data here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-expo?auth-store=secure-store#initialize-a-react-native-app

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';
import * as aesjs from 'aes-js';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';

// As Expo's SecureStore does not support values larger than 2048
// bytes, an AES-256 key is generated and stored in SecureStore, while
// it is used to encrypt/decrypt values stored in AsyncStorage.
class LargeSecureStore {
  private async _encrypt(key: string, value: string) {
    const encryptionKey = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(256 / 8));

    const cipher = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(encryptionKey, new aesjs.Counter(1));
    const encryptedBytes = cipher.encrypt(aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(value));

    await SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptionKey));

    return aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
  }

  private async _decrypt(key: string, value: string) {
    const encryptionKeyHex = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
    if (!encryptionKeyHex) {
      return encryptionKeyHex;
    }

    const cipher = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(encryptionKeyHex), new aesjs.Counter(1));
    const decryptedBytes = cipher.decrypt(aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(value));

    return aesjs.utils.utf8.fromBytes(decryptedBytes);
  }

  async getItem(key: string) {
    const encrypted = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    if (!encrypted) { return encrypted; }

    return await this._decrypt(key, encrypted);
  }

  async removeItem(key: string) {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key);
  }

  async setItem(key: string, value: string) {
    const encrypted = await this._encrypt(key, value);

    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, encrypted);
  }
}

const supabaseUrl = YOUR_REACT_NATIVE_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseAnonKey = YOUR_REACT_NATIVE_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY

const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey, {
  auth: {
    storage: new LargeSecureStore(),
    autoRefreshToken: true,
    persistSession: true,
    detectSessionInUrl: false,
  },
});
```